# Is there a way to use generics to type a complex object array that accurately compares a React component and its props type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript, typescript-definitions

My team has created typescript types definitions for an API that we're using, so we aren't able to touch the source code, just the definitions.

We have a function called `add` that essentially adds one or more react components to the main program. The `props` property of the object should depend on the component type listed on the `component` property.

It looks like this:

```js
add(arg1, arg2, {
//some other args
children: [{
  id: string1,
  //BackButton can be a functional or class-based component
  component: BackButton,
  //BackButtonProps will be defined within BackButton
  props: BackButtonProps
},
  {
  id: string2,
  //SkipButton can be a functional or class-based component
  component: SkipButton,
  //SkipButtonProps will be defined within SkipButton
  props: SkipButtonProps
}
]
});
```

For reference, there is an alternate (overloaded) version of the function that only adds one component instead of multiple that I've been able to figure out the typescript for. It looks like this:

```js
add<T>(
    id: string,
    component: ComponentType<T>,
    props: T
  ): void;
```

My question is this -- since the number of children components is unknown, how can I use a generic on the `add` function so that all the children components are correctly typed (the `props` and `component` properties match up)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic signature of `add` would look like this.

```
declare function add<T extends any[]>(arg1: any, arg2: any, arg3: {
    children: [...{ [K in keyof T]: {
      id: string,
      component: T[K]
      props: React.ComponentProps<T[K]>     
    }}]
}): void
```

The generic type `T` would store a tuple where each element is a react component. For each element with the index `K` of the passed array, the `component` type would be used as the type in `T[K]` and the `props` type would have to be `React.ComponentProps<T[K]>`.

Let's see this in action:

```
const BackButton = (props: {a: string}) => {
    return <div></div>
}

const SkipButton = (props: {b: string}) => {
    return <div></div>
}

add(0, 0, {
    children: [
        {
            id: "1",
            component: BackButton,
            props: { a: "123" }
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            component: SkipButton,
            props: { b: "123" }
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            component: SkipButton,
            props: { a: "123" } // Error: Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ b: string; }'
        }
    ]
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=3&pln=15&pc=1#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQCUCmBDAxsgZnGCJAIjkx2NFABM0sAbDMpXAVwDscwZ2kNrqAHgAqSNAA8EadtQDOfdgE8A2gF0AfAAomAcwCMALgWKANHzg6ATEYxKzugMxGA3qACQWABZh61MuyNlADoQ5yRlAGkkMF4AazRFGFwkYVUXdyRo6iNZBDgYnRMMpCxCWHZpBCNhSNViqAIoWSN0bAQggGEynkqABUbZEVr1JDd3AF9xupBxgEojADcYMGoqEDXQUvZcpAAhbFjd1gQEHiQAXiRNBpgmlwwcvIK5i5HXEDcyBFY4XkFqMALdSCAD0AKBoHGay2OwAyrEwFAjiczpdrgMXAAjR75dg6F7nN7uL4-P7g4FgwHqSFrfjUTQABjMTKQ7w83l8-kC7jcbLcbhWRmIemIRQ%20-NK0B67CqewOyNO7DF-LcNzurL4Qr0lgcxCQUPF42VvJ5AuyJEsotNkvKlSM8MRCp4xtVGI12JI2t1%20p5Rp5fLNQt1Lpt0tlDqRx0VLrVzQ1D09Or14yQIJBSAAonACHBqoooGgkAByMIJ3K4nQAbn1Rei8nYMGQGFksjAOnYGEx9ELpyQCHzhZLSA95YK1fGRd97mmcyAA)

Comment: Thanks, it works! I've never seen an array/tuple indexed like that: "...{" can you explain that syntax or a link to explain how that works? It looks a lot like an object index signature, but I haven't seen the "..." used like that I don't think...

Comment: This syntax allows us to iterate over the passed tuple and use the index `K` to fill the generic type `T`. It's the only way to solve problems like here, where you need to have constraints inside array elements which are independent from other array elements. There is no documentation for this feature sadly.